# Can a subscriber database pull from the publisher in a replication scenario

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, database-replication, pull

With SQL Server 2012 or later, is it possible to set up replication in such a way that a subscriber can *pull* data from the publisher, instead of the publisher pushing data out to it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called a Pull Subscription where the replication agent runs at the subscriber and is covered in [Subscribe to Publications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151170.aspx) and [Create a Pull Subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151225.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. According that page, SQL Server 2012 doesn't have it, which is odd, since it seems to have been introduced in 2008.

Comment: That is incorrect.  Pull subscriptions exist in every version.